# Magento admin session username when in cron

Tags: php, magento, session

When you are working in the adminhtml backend of your module, this code returns the username of the currently logged in user:

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getUsername()
```

What value would the above code return, when the magento cron is executing one of my controller method in my custom module? Will it say "cron" or something equivalent? Or will it be empty?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that should return null. Cron Jobs are not run as an admin user but yet as a core controller.  What are you looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

In controller of cron, we can not refer to admin session. It is like front controller thats why we have no reference to admin user session.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get admin session that whay. But you can get admins user names if you need them.
You can create admin which name is "cron" and get his data for example. Below how to get admin list

http://www.mage-shop.com/blog/magento-tips-tricks/get-admin-accounts

```
$model = Mage::getModel(”admin/user”);
$admins = $model->getCollection();
foreach($admins as $admin){
  $admin->getUsername();//get username of admin.
  $admin->getWhatYouWant();//or other fields.
}
```